# how to set tmp disk variable on nextflow

Tags: slurm, nextflow

I want to add the tmp disk value to my nextflow process.

CPU and memory requirements are setup, but how can I add the tmp disk value?
The data is important for the scheduler (slurm) to select a suitable node.

The nextflow process header cloud be:

```
process TEST {
  echo true
  cpus '8'
  memory '40 GB'
  script:
    """
    """
}
```

This value is called in slurm tmp disk, viewable with `squeue -o "%C %m %d"`, column `MIN_TMP_DISK`.

If any information is missing, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [clusterOptions](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-clusteroptions) process directive with the [SLURM](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html#slurm) executor. From the [sbatch](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) docs, it looks like you are looking for the `--tmp` option:

> --tmp=[units]
>
> Specify a minimum amount of temporary disk space per node. Default units are megabytes. Different units can be
> specified using the suffix [K|M|G|T].

For example:

```
process TEST {

    debug true

    clusterOptions '--tmp=1T'

    cpus 8
    memory 40.GB

    """
    echo "Hello world"
    """
}
```